# Pandas one liner to filter rows by nunique count on a specific column

Tags: python, pandas

In pandas, I regularly use the following to filter a dataframe by number of occurrences

```
df = df.groupby('A').filter(lambda x: len(x) >= THRESHOLD)
```

Assume `df` has another column `'B'` and I want to filter the dataframe this time by the count of unique values on that column, I would expect something like

```
df = df.groupby('A').filter(lambda x: len(np.unique(x['B'])) >= THRESHOLD2)
```

But that doesn't seem to work, what would be the right approach?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It should working nice with [`nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.nunique.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'B':list('abccee'),
                   'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
                   'A':list('aabbcc')})

print (df)
   A  B  E
0  a  a  5
1  a  b  3
2  b  c  6
3  b  c  9
4  c  e  2
5  c  e  4

THRESHOLD2 = 2
df1 = df.groupby('A').filter(lambda x: x['B'].nunique() >= THRESHOLD2)
print (df1)
   A  B  E
0  a  a  5
1  a  b  3
```

But if need faster solution use [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df2 = df[df.groupby('A')['B'].transform('nunique') >= THRESHOLD2]
print (df2)
   A  B  E
0  a  a  5
1  a  b  3
```

**Timings**:

```
np.random.seed(123)
N = 1000000
L = list('abcde') 
df = pd.DataFrame({'B': np.random.choice(L, N, p=(0.75,0.0001,0.0005,0.0005,0.2489)),
                   'A':np.random.randint(10000,size=N)})
df = df.sort_values(['A','B']).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)

THRESHOLD2 = 3

In [403]: %timeit df.groupby('A').filter(lambda x: x['B'].nunique() >= THRESHOLD2)
1 loop, best of 3: 3.05 s per loop

In [404]: %timeit df[df.groupby('A')['B'].transform('nunique')>= THRESHOLD2]
1 loop, best of 3: 558 ms per loop
```

**Caveat**

The results do not address performance given the number of groups, which will affect timings a lot for some of these solutions.

Comment: I was so close... :/

Comment: @bluesummers The answer was in your title :)

Comment: @ScottBoston - yes, it is faster. I tried find timings.