# group by columns then filter based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a df and I want to filter out a column based on a grouping. I want to keep group by combinations ((`cc`, `odd`, `tree1`, and `tree2`) if day > 4, then keep it, otherwise drop it

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['cc'] = ['BB', 'BB', 'BB', 'BB','BB', 'BB','BB', 'BB', 'DD', 'DD', 'DD', 'DD', 'DD', 'DD', 'DD', 'DD', 'ZZ', 'ZZ', 'ZZ', 'ZZ', 'ZZ', 'ZZ', 'ZZ', 'ZZ']
df['odd'] = [3434, 3434, 3434, 3434, 3435, 3435, 3435, 3435, 3434, 3434, 3434, 3434, 3435, 3435, 3435, 3435, 3434, 3434, 3434, 3434, 3435, 3435, 3435, 3435]
df['tree1'] = ['ASP', 'ASP', 'ASP', 'ASP', 'SAP', 'SAP', 'SAP', 'SAP', 'ASP', 'ASP', 'ASP', 'ASP', 'SAP', 'SAP', 'SAP', 'SAP', 'ASP', 'ASP', 'ASP', 'ASP', 'SAP', 'SAP', 'SAP', 'SAP']
df['tree2'] = ['ATK', 'ATK','ATK','ATK','ATK','ATK','ATK','ATK', 'ATK', 'ATK','ATK','ATK','ATK','ATK','ATK','ATK', 'ATK', 'ATK','ATK','ATK','ATK','ATK','ATK','ATK']
df['day'] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 3, 5, 7, 1, 2, 6, 8, 2, 4, 6, 8]
df
```

I tried this but this drops any row with day value smaller than 4

```
df_grouped = df.groupby(['cc', 'odd', 'tree1', 'tree2']).filter(df['day'] > 4)
```

I get this error `TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable`

And tried this

```
df_grouped = df.groupby(['cc', 'odd', 'tree1', 'tree2']).filter(lambda x: x['day'] > 4)
```

I get this error `TypeError: filter function returned a Series, but expected a scalar bool`.

I searched and tried to solve these errors but the proposed solution did not work for me. I would like to get a df as below:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame()
df1['cc'] = ['BB', 'BB','BB', 'BB', 'DD', 'DD', 'DD', 'DD', 'DD', 'DD', 'DD', 'DD', 'ZZ', 'ZZ', 'ZZ', 'ZZ', 'ZZ', 'ZZ', 'ZZ', 'ZZ']
df1['odd'] = [3435, 3435, 3435, 3435, 3434, 3434, 3434, 3434, 3435, 3435, 3435, 3435, 3434, 3434, 3434, 3434, 3435, 3435, 3435, 3435]
df1['tree1'] = ['SAP', 'SAP', 'SAP', 'SAP', 'ASP', 'ASP', 'ASP', 'ASP', 'SAP', 'SAP', 'SAP', 'SAP', 'ASP', 'ASP', 'ASP', 'ASP', 'SAP', 'SAP', 'SAP', 'SAP']
df1['tree2'] = ['ATK','ATK','ATK','ATK', 'ATK', 'ATK','ATK','ATK','ATK','ATK','ATK','ATK', 'ATK', 'ATK','ATK','ATK','ATK','ATK','ATK','ATK']
df1['day'] = [3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 3, 5, 7, 1, 2, 6, 8, 2, 4, 6, 8]
df1
```

I have tried to use the logical function of `any` but I could not make it work, it returns only `True` or `False` to me instead of a filtered dataframe.

Comment: Can't you just filter the df first prior to grouping?. Do you even need to `groupby` after filtering? `groupby` is for aggregating generally

Comment: No, the filtering works on the groups, I want to keep the rows that has values bigger than 4 based on the groupby because the groupby defines the grouping of the day. If I filter then groupby it will drop all rows that are 4 or smaller which is something I don't want

Comment: Your question is then ill-formed you want to filter by group size correct?

Comment: Not group size, I want to check the max day value based on groupby, if it is bigger than 4, then keep the rows of this group, if not, drop the all rows of these group. I think my question cannot be clearer :)

Comment: @coldspeed why it is duplicate? am not asking for a simple group filtering, please read my question again. The duplicate question does not provide solution to my problem at all.

Comment: As EdChum said, you can filter before grouping, Why do it after?

Comment: IIUC you want `df_grouped = df.groupby(['cc', 'odd', 'tree1', 'tree2']).filter(lambda x: (x['day'] > 4).any())` @coldspeed I think the OP wants to filter the groups based on membership, so filter the groups if none of the days are greater than 4 for that grouping, you could filter prior to the grouping

Comment: @coldspeed because it removes all rows which have values of 4 and smaller. I do not want that. I want only to remove the groups that max value is 4. Please see the two dataframe to see the difference. Filtering will remove group 1 and row from any other groups that it 4 or smaller.

Comment: Okay, one second.

Comment: Did you try `df_grouped = df.groupby(['cc', 'odd', 'tree1', 'tree2']).filter(lambda x: (x['day'] > 4).any())` I think this is what you want

Comment: I've reopened the question. Pardon my misunderstanding.

Comment: Many thanks, @EdChum. your solution works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now that I've understood what you want, let's try something like `transform` + `any`:

```
df[df.assign(key=df.day > 4)
     .groupby(['cc', 'odd', 'tree1', 'tree2']).key.transform('any')
]
```

Or,

```
df[df.day.gt(4).groupby([df.cc, df.odd, df.tree1, df.tree2]).transform('any')]
```

```
    cc   odd tree1 tree2  day
4   BB  3435   SAP   ATK    3
5   BB  3435   SAP   ATK    4
6   BB  3435   SAP   ATK    5
7   BB  3435   SAP   ATK    6
8   DD  3434   ASP   ATK    2
9   DD  3434   ASP   ATK    3
10  DD  3434   ASP   ATK    4
11  DD  3434   ASP   ATK    5
12  DD  3435   SAP   ATK    1
13  DD  3435   SAP   ATK    3
14  DD  3435   SAP   ATK    5
15  DD  3435   SAP   ATK    7
16  ZZ  3434   ASP   ATK    1
17  ZZ  3434   ASP   ATK    2
18  ZZ  3434   ASP   ATK    6
19  ZZ  3434   ASP   ATK    8
20  ZZ  3435   SAP   ATK    2
21  ZZ  3435   SAP   ATK    4
22  ZZ  3435   SAP   ATK    6
23  ZZ  3435   SAP   ATK    8
```

Comment: Your first method is the faster method here, I added timings, it looks like the `transform` is faster at coercing back to the orig df than using `filter`

Comment: @EdChum Thank you!

Comment: @coldspeed both solutions work like a charm, thanks. As Edchum wrote the first solution is much faster when I run on 25 million rows df

Answer (score 2):

IIUC you want:

```
In[116]:
df_grouped = df.groupby(['cc', 'odd', 'tree1', 'tree2']).filter(lambda x: (x['day'] > 4).any())
df_grouped

Out[116]: 
    cc   odd tree1 tree2  day
4   BB  3435   SAP   ATK    3
5   BB  3435   SAP   ATK    4
6   BB  3435   SAP   ATK    5
7   BB  3435   SAP   ATK    6
8   DD  3434   ASP   ATK    2
9   DD  3434   ASP   ATK    3
10  DD  3434   ASP   ATK    4
11  DD  3434   ASP   ATK    5
12  DD  3435   SAP   ATK    1
13  DD  3435   SAP   ATK    3
14  DD  3435   SAP   ATK    5
15  DD  3435   SAP   ATK    7
16  ZZ  3434   ASP   ATK    1
17  ZZ  3434   ASP   ATK    2
18  ZZ  3434   ASP   ATK    6
19  ZZ  3434   ASP   ATK    8
20  ZZ  3435   SAP   ATK    2
21  ZZ  3435   SAP   ATK    4
22  ZZ  3435   SAP   ATK    6
23  ZZ  3435   SAP   ATK    8
```

So this will filter out the groups where within the group none of the `'day'` values are greater than 4

**timings**:

```
%timeit df[df.day.gt(4).groupby([df.cc, df.odd, df.tree1, df.tree2]).transform('any')]
%timeit df.groupby(['cc', 'odd', 'tree1', 'tree2']).filter(lambda x: (x['day'] > 4).any())
%timeit df[df.assign(key=df.day > 4).groupby(['cc', 'odd', 'tree1', 'tree2']).key.transform('any')]
100 loops, best of 3: 5.9 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 5.42 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 3.62 ms per loop
```

So @coldspeed's first method is the fastest here

Comment: If you can group on the boolean column, you can avoid the lambda totally. Nice answer tho.

Comment: @coldspeed sure, will try that

Comment: (oh, that's in my answer but sure you can try something similar)

Comment: @coldspeed ah right, will leave it then, I'm a bit old school when it comes to `pandas` these days

Comment: @EdChum - yes, I have similar experience, `filter` is obviously very slow - `https://stackoverflow.com/a/47415132/2901002`

Comment: @jezrael I'd have to look at the source but I'm guessing that `filter` is multi-purpose in that it's looking to generate a boolean series for each group to determine membership and recreate the boolean mask for the groups and return a df, with `transform` you know you just have to generate a boolean mask for the original df with the same index so it's less guesswork and more scope for optimisation

Comment: It seems @coldspeed solution are 4 times faster on a 25 million rows df `1 loop, best of 3: 21.7 s per loop` (EdChum)
`1 loop, best of 3: 5.8 s per loop` (coldspeed1)
`1 loop, best of 3: 5.52 s per loop` (coldspeed2)