# Optimize python script

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to make my script less resource heavy or just looking for an easier code for python to process for the following problem:

Example Table (dataset.xlsx):

```
no order materials status         Status_id
1  1000  100       available       1 
2  1000  200       not available   3 
3  1001  500       Feb-20          2 
4  1002  400       available       1 
5  1002  300       not available   3 
6  1002  600       available       1 
7  1002  900       available       1 
8  1003  700       available       1 
9  1003  800       available       1
```

I wanted to get the new column that duplicates max Status_id per order.

```
df=dataset
df.groupby('Status_id').max()
df['Max'] = df.groupby('order')['Status_id'].transform('max')
df
```

and I get:

```
no order materials status         Status_id   Max
1  1000  100       available       1          3
2  1000  200       not available   3          3
3  1001  500       Feb-20          2          2
4  1002  400       available       1          3
5  1002  300       not available   3          3
6  1002  600       available       1          3
7  1002  900       available       1          3
8  1003  700       available       1          1
9  1003  800       available       1          1
```

Although it looks simple and it works with small sets of data, but my actual data has 80k+ rows of data and maximum of 80 status_ids, and so it takes hours to calculate all that.

any suggestions?

Comment: IMO for large file I prefer using Dask(https://dask.org/). Dask will automatically prallelize your operations. It also provides an API almost equal as the pandas one, so you are going to feel comfortable with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to sort by `'Status_id'` first and then take the last value from each group:

```
df = df.sort_values('Status_id')
df['Max'] = df.groupby('order')['Status_id'].transform('last')
```

Comment: Do you have some test? It should be interesting see if it is faster.

Comment: @jezrael No. Maybe you can test it.

Comment: Idea for improve answer, be free use sample dataset from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47415088/pandas-one-liner-to-filter-rows-by-nunique-count-on-a-specific-column/47415132#47415132)